# why I cant see my layout file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have created a class which extends ArrayAdapter class. But while doint 
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxxx,..) I cannot see my layout file. I dont know what does that mean. In other activity I can see it very well using R.layout.xxx.!

Comment: probably you have the wrong import for the R class

Comment: Noo I tried with Android.R and android.support.v7.appcompat.R too

Comment: as I said, you have imported the wrong R class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple solution for this issue.

Suppose your package name is

```
com.xyz.package
```

Now If you will look at the top of your code 
you would find

```
import android.R;
```

replace this with

```
import com.xyz.package.R;
```

after replacing above import if you find still error that means your layout.xml file in res directory has errors. rectify it, clean and build it in eclipse.

Comment: No It depends on what that class file need android.R or package.r. Just check the error and then take necessary steps.

Comment: I think you are using latest amdroid sdk which includes v7appCompact.

Comment: yes i am using latest android sdk, initially i was not able to figure out why eclipse is creating two projects for every new project :)

Comment: You should delete v7appcompact_2 because eachtime you create a new project you will find another folder.